# I'm having problems with a “too few arguments to function” error in my c program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf, sizeof, function-call

I typed this program from Boris Allen's book C programming: principles & practice on pg18 using Dev-C++ 5.11, its supposed to produce the following output text:

```
Size of whoCount is 2
Size of newCount is 2
Size of Printf() is 2
```

I don't know how to fix this error.

```
error: too few arguments to function 'printf'.
```

(The compiler also mentions something with a function in 'main.)

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int whoCount, newCount;
    printf("Size of whoCount is %d\n",
      sizeof(whoCount));
    printf("Size of newCount is %d\n",
      sizeof(newCount));
    printf("Size of printf() is %d\n",
      sizeof(printf()));
}
```

It's supposed to work but I don't know why it does not. It's an example program from the book C programming: principles & practice on pg18. The previous examples worked flawlessly but I'm stuck with this one giving me an error: too few arguments to function 'printf'. I am new to programming and I don't know how to fix it so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "something with a function in 'main'" I am 100% sure that is not what the compiler mentioned. If you have error message, always post exact and complete error messages. Not something that is unrecognizable.

Comment: If this is an example from the book at page 18, I suggest you ditch it. You barely started and it already led you astray.

Comment: Suggest picking up another book.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` the compiler thinks that you want to call printf and zero parameters is definitely wrong.

- `sizeof(&printf)` gives the size of the *function pointer*
- `sizeof(printf("hello"))` gives the size of the function return type
- `sizeof(printf)` is invalid in standard C (it violates 6.5.3.4) but many compilers support it as an extension.

Your code invokes undefined behaviour as you use the incorrect format to print the `size_t` type.
Also your `main` function definition is wrong. function `main` **must** return `int`

```
int main(void)
{
    int whoCount, newCount;
    printf("Size of whoCount is %zu\n",
      sizeof(whoCount));
    printf("Size of newCount is %zu\n",
      sizeof(newCount));
    printf("Size of printf is %zu\n",
      sizeof(printf));
    printf("Size of &printf is %zu\n",
      sizeof(&printf));
    printf("Size of printf(\"hello\") is %zu\n",
      sizeof(printf("hello")));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nY1obxEP8

`printf` in `sizeof(printf("hello"))` is not called and `sizeof` only determines the type of this expression.

It is not possible to get the size of the `printf`s code using `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

From the C Stanfdard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
> defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

The type of an expression with the `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. So to output the value of such an expression you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d` as for example

```
printf("Size of whoCount is %zu\n",
  sizeof(whoCount));
```

To write a call of `printf` you have to specify at least one argument even if the expression with the call of `printf` is not evaluated as for example

```
printf("Size of printf() is %zu\n",
  sizeof(printf( "Hello World!")));
```

The function is declared like

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

Pay attention to that in this call

```
printf("Size of printf() is %zu\n",
  sizeof(printf( "Hello World!")));
```

there will be in fact outputted the value of the expression `sizeof( int )` because the return type of the function `printf` is `int`. The string `"Hello World!"` will not be outputted because the expression `sizeof(printf( "Hello World!"))` is not evaluated. The compiler just determines the type of the expression.

Also bear in mind the you may not use a function as an operand of the `sizeof` operator. That is you may not write `sizeof( printf )`. From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 1 **The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
> function type** or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of
> such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member